# Assign strings in a line to variables using bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have the following text file for which I need to compare values from each line, namely items 2-4 against items 5-7. I'm stuck with bash/awk/sed on this one.

Sample data:

```
[hartford tmp]$ cat flist
a1 1 2 3 x y z
b1 3 2 1 z y x
c1 1 2 3 1 2 3
d1 4 5 6 6 5 4
e1 a b c a b c
f1 x y z x y z
```

It works with the following script but its just unbearably slow, probably because all of the `echo`s.

```
[hartford tmp]$ cat pdelta.sh
#!/bin/bash

cat flist |while read rec; do
    f1="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $1 }')"
    f2="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $2 }')"
    f3="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $3 }')"
    f4="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $4 }')"
    f5="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $5 }')"
    f6="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $6 }')"
    f7="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $7 }')"

    if [[ "x${f2} x${f3} x${f4}" != "x${f5} x${f6} x${f7}" ]]; then
            echo "$f1 DOES NOT MATCH"
    fi
done
```

When run, the output is exactly what I'm looking for but it's too slow when dealing with a file that's 50k+ lines long.

```
[hartford]$ ./pdelta.sh
a1 DOES NOT MATCH
b1 DOES NOT MATCH
d1 DOES NOT MATCH
```

What is a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just for completeness, note also that `set $rec` would assign the first field to `$1`, the second to `$2`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk` to output all the matching id's:

```
awk '{ if ($2 == $5 && $3 == $6 && $4 == $7) { print $1 } }' < flist
```

Comment: Or `$2 == $5 && $3 == $6 && $4 == $7 { print $1 }`.

Comment: Or `$2$3$4 == $5$6$7 { print $1 }` (Slightly less robust but I believe satisfies the problem constraints.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `read` to assign the variables:

```
$ while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7; do stuff; done <flist
```

Answer (score 4):

A few fixes:

1. Don't `cat` a single file into the pipe; just redirect standard input for the loop.
2. `read` can split each line into the appropriate variables.
3. Since you are using the bash `[[...]]` construct, you don't need to use the old trick of prefixing a possibly empty string with a single character. Just compare corresponding values directly.

So your loop reduces to

```
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7; do
    if [[ $f2 != $f5 || $f3 != $f6 || $f4 != $f7 ]]; then
        echo "$f1 DOES NOT MATCH"
    fi
done < flist
```

You can also use an array to reduce it even further

```
while read -a f; do
    if [[ ${f[@]:1:3} != ${f[@]:4:3} ]]; then
        echo "${f[0]} DOES NOT MATCH"
    fi
done < flist
```

The `${f[@]:x:y}` notation expands to `y` elements starting at index `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Using perl:

```
perl -lane 'print $F[0] if @F[1..3] ne @F[4..6]' input_file
```

Comment: Are you sure? `perl -e '@v=(0,1,2,1); print @v[0,1] eq @v[2,3]'`

Comment: You do not need the `split`, `-a` alread takes care of that: `perl -lane 'print $F[0] if @F[1..3] ne @F[4..6]'`.

Comment: There is more than one way to do it (in Perl).

Answer (score 0):

Python solution:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7 = line.split()
    if not (f2, f3, f4) == (f5, f6, f7):
        print f1, "does not match"
```

Usage:

```
$ python f.py < flist
a1 does not match
b1 does not match
d1 does not match
```